# Question on Contraction Mapping Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there is a function $g \in C[0,1]$ such that

$$
2g(x) + \cos(x^2) = \int_0^1{g(s)\ \cos(sx^2)\mathrm{d}s}
$$
for $$x \in [0,1]$$

I'm a bit confused on what the Integral Operator $T(g)$ would look like. I know we can use the complete $d_\infty$ metric to show the contraction property, I think I have an idea on how I would apply it, however what I am unsure about is that to apply the contraction mapping theorem in the first place, we would need our mapping for T on the appropriate metric space to also give us another continous function on $[0,1]$.
This would mean showing for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that when $|x - y| < \delta$, $|T(g)(x) - T(g)(y)| < \epsilon $ .

Is my interpretation correct? How would I prove this?
In general, how would I go about tackling this?

Comment: isn't it $\cos(s^2)$?

Comment: @JulesBesson Unfortunately not, which is what confuses me more

Comment: it works too, don't worry :)

Comment: what is your norm?

Comment: I believe the infinity norm is most appropriate as it would make C[0,1] a complete metric space?

Comment: yes exactly !!!

Comment: I'm just a bit confused about how I would prove the T mapping would spit out another continous function on [0, 1]. On glancing, it seems trivial enough but showing it with epsilons and deltas is another thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theorem is used to exhibit unique fixed points, here you want $T$ to be define such that its fixed point $g$ verifies your equality.

Let us set
$$T(f)(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_0^1 f(s) \cos(sx^2)ds - \cos(x^2)\right) $$

$T$ is affine, hence its differential is its linear part:
$$dT_f (h)(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 h(s) \cos(sx^2)ds$$
We have for $x \neq 0$
$$|dT_f (h) (x) | \leq \frac{1}{2} \|h\|_\infty \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{2} \|h\|_\infty$$
and
$$|dT_f (h) (0) | \leq \frac{1}{2} \|h\|_\infty$$

So
$$\|dT_f\| \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
(in fact this is an equality, you can show it...)

This gives you that $T$ is $\frac{1}{2}$-contracting (simple inequality involving the norm of the differential), thus it admits an (unique) fixed point $g$. You can see that $g$ is what you want!

When your operator is differentiable, always look for the differential.

Comment: Thank you!! I just realised I had a mistake in my question, the integrand was actually $g(s)cos(sx^2)$, could you show me if this is the case.

Comment: yes no problem, let me edit

Comment: Is it ok for you (I dod not detail everything so you still have some technical work to do)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Since the operator is differentiable, this means it automatically follows that it is continuous from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, plus since it is affine, it is equal up to an addition of a constant to its differential, which was proven here to be continuous. (but this is overkill, it's just a remark)